# windows task scheduler - how to run a task if two trigger criteria are met

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run a task on log on only if the computer is idle. I can also achieve what I want if I can run the task with one idle trigger and make sure it only runs once per system start up to stop it repeatedly starting the script every time the system is idle.

OS: windows 10 1903
task scheduler 1.0

Comment: *run a task on log on only if the computer is idle*... Huh? How would that condition ever be met?

Comment: run on log on trigger is met then check for idle trigger if both = true run task

Comment: I don't think the *on idle* trigger would ever be true during logon.

Comment: That's the point. I want the script to run only once per log on and only if idle.

Comment: So you never want it to run? Or only after logon, when the computer _becomes_ idle? Because during the logon sequence, the computer will never reach an idle state to trigger an on idle scheduled task. You can configure the logon trigger to have a set delay of X minutes, but not a variable time based on interactions with the system.

Comment: only after logon, when the computer becomes idle and only once so it does not restart the program every time the computer is idle.

Comment: What you actually want is a script that runs as soon as the computer becomes idle, but only once per logon session. Your question is suffering from the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) in that you're trying to accomplish this with two triggers and running into trouble accomplishing that. I recommend you edit your question to state your goal as I have defined it and let the answers provide a solution that meets your requirements, whether it involves multiple triggers or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I was a little dumb. The option I was looking for was under conditions called "start the task only if the computer is idle for X minutes". So I just used a trigger for log on of any user and this condition and it did what I wanted.